# NoClassDefFoundException in a provided .class file

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, artificial-intelligence, inner-classes

I am trying to build a project in Eclipse using some files provided to me for a school assignment (I have plenty of time before its due).  I'm running into a weird problem and I haven't found an answer yet.  The project is a game played between two AI players.  The archers are controlled by the enemy.  The archer's code came in the form of a .class file, and I do not have any other source code for it.  Everything appears to work fine until the archers try to move, then this happens:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ArcherAgent$1
at ArcherAgent.isFourDir(ArcherAgent.java:332)
at ArcherAgent.bestToMove(ArcherAgent.java:246)
at ArcherAgent.makeDecision(ArcherAgent.java:218)
at ArcherAgent.middleStep(ArcherAgent.java:150)
at edu.cwru.sepia.agent.ThreadIntermediary.run(ThreadIntermediary.java:140)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ArcherAgent$1
```

The $1 indicates to me that it's looking for an inner class.  I've tried placing the file in various locations to no avail, and I've also tried using clean and build in Eclipse when I noticed the $1.  Are there other ways I could approach the problem?  I'm not entirely sure how to handle the fact that it seems to be missing an inner class, and I've been searching around now and I don't think I've found anything yet.

I'm sorry for any trouble.

Comment: Each class has its own .class file. Did you get only one?

Comment: Show your code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right the class which is missing is an inner class. This class is in another file which is generated by the compiler. When you dont have a file named like this its missing so you have to get the source for the outer class or find the missing compiled inner class somewhere else.

Comment: Exactly right. To expand a bit, the ArcherAgent$1 class is an anonymous inner class. These classes are created by code like this: `new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                // Do something
                        }
                };`. The class file you are looking for is called ArcherAgent$1.class.

Comment: So clear it to me. You have the source and in the build folder the class file exists?

Comment: Turns out it was exactly as you said.  I was missing the compiled inner class, which it turns out was also provided.

Answer (score 0):

Look at import block for ArcherAgent class. I'm sure you miss some lib which uses your ArcherAgent class. NoClassDefFoundError means that classes in import block are not in classpath.